# Determining driver, spatial reference and other props from an open GDAL layer

Tags: python, gdal, shapely, fiona

I have a very large network share full of data (raster, vector, sometimes mixed inside of geopackage and/or file geodatabase containers).  I have a set of classes that crawl through it all and use `arcpy.Describe()` to extract from each dataset its datatype, extent and spatial reference system.  That then goes into a single enterprise db layer that shows our spatial holdings and a bit of heritage data of each element.

I'd like to try making it open source for other users to run who do not have licenses. GDAL also offers me some more insight into what specific driver is being used, to further categorize the data, theoretically.

I'd like to avoid hardcoding around file extensions and ask GDAL (or fiona, or shapely, not picky here) instead - [update] because I don't know what sort of files the indexer will encounter.  Assuming a subset of the data, I can do something like this:

```
import gdal

filelist = [
    '/share/Data/Terrain/N43W072.hgt',
    '/share/Data/Terrain/N43W072_StrahlerOrder_8.tif',
    '/share/Data/Terrain/N43W072_Channels_Clipped.shp',
    '/share/Data/Terrain/N43W072_Channels.shp',
    '/share/Data/Network/NH/nh_road_network.gdb',
    '/share/Data/Network/MA/ma_road_network.gpkg'
]

for f in filelist:
    try:
        dataset = gdal.Open(f)
    except:
        # do stuff
```

but I am not clear how to then summon the properties of `dataset` (I'm presuming that the open dataset object holds the elements I'm looking for). I've looked at https://gdal.org/python/ but there is nothing I can find that says "here is how you get all the properties of an `gdal.Open()` object."

Ultimately the properties I want to see would be presented something like this:

```
{
    "driver": "GPKG",
    "driver_long_name": "GeoPackage raster"
    "type": "Raster",
    "extent": [(miny, minx), (maxy, minx), (maxy, maxx), (miny, maxx)]
    "CRS" : {'epsg:4326'}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`gdal.Info` might be the simplest way:

```
ds = gdal.Open('/vsicurl/https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/raw/master/autotest/gcore/data/3376.tif')
info = gdal.Info(ds, options='-json')
print(info.keys())

dict_keys(['description', 'driverShortName', 'driverLongName', 'files', 'size', 'coordinateSystem', 'geoTransform', 'metadata', 'cornerCoordinates', 'wgs84Extent', 'rat', 'bands'])
```

But if you want to figure out how to pull that information directly from the open `Dataset` object look at the methods that start with `Get` in the [documentation for `gdal.Dataset`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Dataset-class.html).